# Is it true that for the Weibull distribution a value of $k$ for $ k > 1 $ indicates that the failure rate increases with time?

Tags: probability, weibull-distribution, failure-rate

When describing the Weibull distribution on Wikipedia, it is claimed, among other things, that

"A value of $ k > 1 $ indicates that the failure rate increases with time."

However, for $ k > 3 $ the failure rate increases with time, but then decreases after a while.

For example for $ k = 4 $ the failure rate  $ h(x;\lambda,4) $ is as follows:

$$ h \left(x \right) = \frac{4~x ^{3}~e^{\frac{x ^{3}~\left(\lambda -x \right)}{\lambda ^{4}}}}{\lambda ^{4}} $$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

The failure rate is $h(x)=f(x)/(1-F(x))$, and when substituted it is 
$$h(x)=\frac{\frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{k-1}e^{-(x/\lambda)^k}}{1-(1-e^{-(x/\lambda)^k})}=\frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{k-1}$$
which increases as $x$ increases if $k>1$.

Comment: I am very, very sorry for making an error in the derivation of $h(x)$.

Comment: @AdvanderVen there is nothing to be sorry. This is the purpose of asking. And, if you think the answer is ok, can you please accept and/or upvote it?